# Pandas column/series name when using groupby and apply

Tags: group-by, apply, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe that I'm grouping by the second level index, selecting a single column, and then applying some function. The function needs to access the column name. Here's a small example of the data:

```
arrays = [["2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008"],
          ["0007_1", "0007_1", "0007_H", "0007_H", 
           "0007_1", "0007_1", "0007_H", "0007_H"]]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["year", "sample"])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(8, 2), index=index, columns=["diff", "pole"])
```

and an example function:

```
def tiny_function(data):
    sample = data.index.get_level_values(level=1)[0]
    score = data.name
    print("sample: {} score: {}".format(sample, score))
```

When just grouping the df by the index I can access the column name as expected, works:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
group_df = df.loc[idx[:, :], "diff"].groupby(level=["sample"])
for key, item in group_df:
    print(item.index.get_level_values(level=1)[0], item.name)
```

It's also returning what's expected when inputting a specific slice of the df to my function, works:

```
tiny_function(df.loc[idx[:,"0007_1"], "diff"])
```

What isn't working is when I apply the function after grouping. NOT working:

```
df.loc[idx[:,:], "diff"].groupby(level="sample").apply(tiny_function)
```

Not sure why this last step isn't working.